# Problem with dll while installing QGIS in windows

Tags: installation, windows, dll

I am having an issue installing QGIS on my windows 10 machine. It used to be finely installed, but due to some reasons I had to uninstall.
It has to do with older (2.16) and newer versions (3.0,3.10..).
I am getting a dll related error as you can see in the image attached.

[image]

Comment: How did you install qgis?

Comment: As I do normally in my other desktops with no issue: via downloading the stable releases from their web page (standalone).